# Book with color pictures of algebraic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces

I have a pretty specific question: I'm looking for a book with color pictures of algebraic surfaces. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The world expert on this appears to be Oliver Labs: see e.g. his PhD thesis (http://www.oliverlabs.net/data/phdthesis_oliver_labs.pdf) and a nice introduction to surfaces with many singularities (in German: http://imaginary.org/sites/all/modules/pubdlcnt/pubdlcnt.php?file=http://imaginary.org/sites/default/files/imaginary-weltrekordflaechen-oliver-labs.pdf&nid=314).

Comment: I ended up translating the second article mentioned above into English: http://www.mariuskempe.net/Writing/Labs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this piece of software.

http://surf.sourceforge.net/

Here is a talk based on this software.  http://www.oliverlabs.net/data/talkAuron2010.pdf

What do you think?